# SQL: how to get max values from tables

Tags: sql

[image]
 the values come from TABLEs `contract`, `tenant`, `property`
THEN i want to get max (expiry_date) according to each idproperty.
the output like:

```
idproperty| property_unit | tenant| expiry_date | idcontract   
 426      |  Car Park     | NGUY  | 2016-05-27  |   1578    
 432      | 13TH FLoor    | wong  | 2015-09-21  |   1455    
 433      | 14TH floor    | HA    | 2016-07-01  |   1629
```

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using??

Comment: tables or columns, you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `OVER PARTITION BY` to find the `max expire_date` of each property_unit

```
SELECT idproperty,
       property_unit,
       tenant,
       expiry_date,
       idcontract
FROM  (SELECT Row_number() OVER (partition BY idproperty, property_unit
                  ORDER BY expiry_date DESC) Rn,
              *
       FROM   tablename) a
WHERE  a.rn = 1
```